# how to validate if data has a trailing "/"

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I have a file containing various information. The fields are delimited by |. One of the fields contains a directory. For example :

```
blah|blah|blah|/usr/local/etc/|blah|blah
```

I need to validate that the path field does not end with a "/". I'm using ksh. Any suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the directory is always in the 4th field

```
line=0
while IFS='|' read -rA fields; do
    let line++
    [[ ${fields[3]} == */ ]] && echo line $line: ends with a slash
done < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Not ksh, but this is a natural job for `awk`:

```
awk -F\| '$4 ~ /\/$/ {
    print "Trailing slash in line "NR":", $4
}' ${file:?}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [ line ~= '(/\w+)+(\||$)' ]
```

My shell syntax is rusty, so this might need a little massaging into shape

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget special path like / (root)
I keep the / (root) in code below

```
echo "blah|blah|blah|/usr/local/etc/|blah|blah|
blah|blah|blah|/|blah|blah
blah|blah|blah|.|blah|blah
blah|blah|blah|/usr/local/etc|blah|blah" \
sed "
  /\/\|/ {
    /\|\/\|/ !s/\/|/|/
    }"
```

explaination:
//\|/  treat line where a "/|" appear
//\|/ ! treat line where "|/|" doesn't appear (here in the case of previous test occur)
s//|/|/  replace "/|" by "|" (here when both test occur successfully)